# How to display the output or error mysql query from perl to the same webpage?

Tags: html, mysql, perl

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Database test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<script>
function validateForm(n,mes)
{
valid=true;
var x=n.value;
var errn="error_"+n.id;
var email = document.getElementById('EMAIL').value;
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
//alert(errn);

if (x==null || x=="" || x.trim()=="")
  {
  document.getElementById(errn).innerHTML=mes;
  valid=false;
  }
  else
  {
  document.getElementById(errn).innerHTML="";
   if(n.id == 'EMAIL') 
    {   
       if (!filter.test(email)) {
         document.getElementById(errn).innerHTML="Please Provide a valid email address";
         email.focus();
         valid=false;
         } else {
         document.getElementById(errn).innerHTML="";
         valid=true;
         }
    }
  }

return valid;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Just a Database test</h1>
<form name="SignUp" action="http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/connectivity.cgi" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
Name :<input id="NAME" type="text" name="name" onblur="validateForm(this,'Name must be filled out');">     <p id="error_NAME"></p>
Email :<input id="EMAIL" type="text" name="email" onblur="validateForm(this,'Email must be filled out');"> <p id="error_EMAIL"></p> 
<input type="submit" value="Send">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**connectivity.cgi**

```
#!C:/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI;
use strict;
use DBI();
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);


print "content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";

my $q=new CGI;
my $name=$q->param('name');
my $email=$q->param('email');


print $q->header;


#connect to database.
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost","root","mukesh",
          {'RaiseError' => 1});

eval {$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp (name VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL)")};
print "creating table emp failed: $@" if $@;
print "<br>";


my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp WHERE email = ?");
$sth->execute($email);
my $rows = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref();
$sth->finish();

if (!$rows) {

$sth=$dbh->prepare_cached(<<SQL);
INSERT INTO emp(name,email) values(?,?)
SQL
$sth->execute($name,$email);
$sth->finish();
} else {
    print "<h4>$email already exists, please enter a new email address<br></h4>";
exit 1;
}



my $sql = qq/select * from emp order by name/; 

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die "Can't prepare $sql:$dbh->errstrn";
#pass sql query to database handle


my $rv = $sth->execute() or die "can't execute the query: $sth->errstrn";



while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
print join(", ",@row),"<br>";
}

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();

print "<br>Total no of records : $rv";

if ($rv>=1){
print "<br>Record has been successfully updated !!!<br>";
}else{
print "<br>Error!!while inserting record<br>";
exit;
}
```

my problem is that after quring the mysql db i want the output to be displayed on the same page as the form is
but when i hit the send button it takes me to a new page and the output/error is displayed like this.

[image]

or

[image: error]

I want the email already existing error to come below the Email box and the output to come
below the send button on the same page as below.
[image: myform]

Do i need to include some other language in my code for this like ajax or php.
i am not sure how to do this as i am being redirected to another page where the details
are displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to understand that:
-The page with the form is a HTML page which displays on its own.
-The activity.cgi is a seperate page - which also displays on its own. The webserver just happens to exceute it and display the output.

One easy way to do what you want is to simply get rid of the HTML file, and output the HTML from the CGI. In perl you can do something like:

```
    print "<html> (all your html here down to the end of the form) ";

    if (!defined $q->param('name'))
    {
      # No parameters were passed - user has not submitted the form.
      print "Please fill in the form and press send.";
    }
    else
    {
       # The parameter exists - so the user has submitted the form
       # Go on with your code to do the database work here and output the results
    }

    print "end html code here </html>";
```

So what happens is that script executes one to show the page, then it executes again when the submit is pressed - only that time it shows the page AND shows the database output.

You could also do what you want with ajax. In that you can make the form submit button perform a javascript xmlhttprequest to your current cgi page and insert the results into your page using innerHTML of a div.

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea